# Why is date being set one day earlier than expected?

Tags: javascript

```
var dateTest = new Date('2015-03-31');
console.log(dateTest);
```

Result:

> Mon Mar 30 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

However I expected this to be March 31. How might I do this?

Comment: It takes the date you pass it as UTC, and then applies your local UTC modificator, which is -4, so 2015-03-31 00 - 4h = 2015-03-30 20

Answer (score 3):

Because it's setting the date according to UTC, and returning it with your local timezone offset. I'd recommend explicitly specifying the timezone offset, if that's what you need, or adding your timezone offset after the fact.

```
var d = new Date('2015-03-31T00:00:00-0400');

// or

var d = new Date('2015-03-31');
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

If you *want* it to be in UTC, you can call the `toUTCString()` method on it instead, which will give you the date you expect, albeit not in your timezone.